# Related to a puzzle. Which is larger: $365 \cdot 365 \cdot (\frac{364}{365})^{365}$ or $364 \cdot 365(\frac{364}{365})^{364}$

Tags: calculus, probability

According to WolframAlpha, the two quantities are identical to over 60 decimal places!

$$365 \cdot 365 \cdot \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{365} \approx x$$

$$364 \cdot 365 \cdot \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{364} \approx y$$

$$x \approx y \approx 48943.523805351118109005476...$$

[WolframAlpha for x](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=365*365*%28364%2F365%29%5E365)

[WolframAlpha for y](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=364*365*%28364%2F365%29%5E364)

By way of history, the quantities arise in a puzzle from [Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability with Solutions](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486653552.html) by Frederick Mosteller.

> Labor laws in Erewhon require factory owners to give every worker a holiday whenever one of them has a birthday and to hire without discrimination on grounds of birthdays. Except for these holidays they work a 365-day year. The owners want to maximize the expected total number of man-days worked per year in a factory. How many workers do factories have in Erewhon?

The book states the answer of 364 or 365 is acceptible, but it would seem to me that one has to be larger than the other!

Now at first one considers a calculus approach. We can maximize the continuous function:

$$365n\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n$$

This has a maximum around $n \approx 364.5$, which is of little help since we then need to evaluate $364$ and $365$.

But from the continuous function, we can deduce the function is monotonically increasing until a maximum, and then it decreases. So if we consider the discrete case, we try to see when the ratio of terms starts decreasing. So we have:

$$\frac{365n\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{n}}{365(n-1)\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{n-1}} \leq 1$$

$$\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{364}{365} \leq 1$$

$$365 \leq n$$

So it seems the maximum is at $n=365$, ever so slightly, if I did my calculations correctly. I would be curious of two things:

**(1)** Is my analysis correct on the discrete case maximum at $n = 365$?

**(2)** Is there a way to compute at which decimal point the values differ? I am worried about loss of significance given that WolframAlpha has trouble!

Comment: Your two values ($x,y$) are equal.  You can see this when you take the ratio later in your question since setting $n=365$ in $\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{364}{365}$ gives $1$

Comment: You must misread/mistyped/mis-something.

Comment: "but it would seem to me that one has to be larger than the other!" Why?.

Comment: It's just as the book says; both answers $364$ and $365$ are valid, since they give the **same** value for the function.

Comment: FYI, the maximum is at $1/\ln(365/364)$, the log mean of $365$ and $364$.

Comment: Thanks everyone for being kind. It's a good lesson for me not to overthink...now time to do some basic arithmetic and algebra drills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{365 \cdot 365 \cdot \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{365}}{364 \cdot 365 \cdot \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{364}} = \left(\frac{365}{364}\right)\left(\frac{364}{365}\right) = 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

As [Brian Moehring](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/694754/brian-moehring)'s question comment states, you can also get this from your ratio by setting $n = 365$ in $\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{364}{365}$. This shows your two values of $x = 365 \cdot 365 \cdot \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{365}$ and $y = 364 \cdot 365 \cdot \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{364}$ are equal to each other.

Comment: Thanks for that, I feel like a fool for overlooking this. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Presh You're welcome. We all sometimes miss quite obvious things. It's happened to me often enough. There's no need to feel like a fool.

Answer (score 2):

Just evaluate and cancel.

$x = 365*365*(\frac {364}{365})^{365} = \frac {365*365}{365^{365}}*364^{365}= \frac{364^{365}}{365^{363}}$

$y = 364*365*(\frac {364}{365})^{364}= \frac {364*364^{364}*365}{365^{364}}=\frac {364^{365}}{365^{363}} = x$